# Pass two ids in a table with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been struggling with creating the Roles in my application, I have installed the gem Rolify and it created a model Role in which this is the code:

```
 class Role < ActiveRecord::Base 
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
 has_many :abilities
 end
```

It also created automatically the joined table users_roles which stores the id of the user and the id of the role that exist in my database. I created 3 roles `Admin` - `Patient` - `Doctor`. My question is how could I pass values to this :users_roles table with a check-boxes in the registration
%% The code in my registration how could I modify it

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :roles %>
    <% Role.all.each do |role| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.role_ids.include(role.id)%>
        <%= role.name %><br />
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

So that in the users_roles table every time i Check Patient for example it makes a connection with my user_id and the role_id in that table

I do not have a roles controller first of all, secondly in my User controller this is my code

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    load_and_authorize_resource

    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def show
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    current_user.update(user_params)
    end
    def user_params
      params[:user].permit(
          {:role_ids => []}
      )
    end
 end
```

Here is the code generated in HTML from the checkboxes

```
       <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user_roles">Roles</label>

        <input id="user_role_ids_" name="user[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        admin<br />
        <input id="user_role_ids_" name="user[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
        patient<br />
        <input id="user_role_ids_" name="user[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
        doctor<br />

  </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your code looks fine..have you added strong parameter :roles_ids=>[] in controller ..? or is there any error?

Comment: Why are you updating current_user instead of @user????

Comment: Your way of using `check_box_tag` corresponds poorly to the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag) on it. Could you post the HTML source resulting from your View-code? That would make it easier to guess what kind of `params` you should expect from your `POST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only saw your HTML today, but this is sure to confuse the browser. Seeing this you should change your `View` code to include the `id` of your role in the `name` parameter, i.e.

```
  <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][#{role.id}]", role.id, @user.role_ids.include(role.id)%>
```

which might do the trick. Look at the resulting `params` hash to see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this will allow the form to add multiple roles to a user:

```
 <% Role.all.each do |role| %>
    <div class="block my-2">
      <%= label_tag "role_#{role.id}", role.name.capitalize %>
      <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.role_ids.include?(role.id), id: "role_#{role.id}" %>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```